# Applying function to all elements at once instead of for each single element?

Tags: java, guava

I need something like [`FluentIterable.transformAndConcat`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v14.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html), however the transform function shall be called only once for all elements in my FluentIterable (so all elements of the FluentIterable shall be passed to my function at once) instead of once for each single element.

Is there anything for this case in Guava, that I missed?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: it is not clear to me what you try to achieve

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that what you want to transform is not individual elements but the collection itself. If you had a `Function<X,Y>` you could transform a `Collection<X>` to a `Collection<Y>` using this method.

What you have is a `Function<Collection<X>, Collection<Y>>`, just call it on your collection using [`Function.apply`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v14.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html#apply%28F%29) and iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Observer pattern,  it function as a listener,

Your objects are listeners, then when you want you fire and event, then all your objects execute the method you want.

I'm afraid that when you fire that event, there must be a cycle informing your objects, first try to understand this pattern in order if it fits your  needs or not.

Cheers